# How to create an Android App with ViewPager as a list item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to create an Android App with showing ListView, and list item should be a ViewPager. Each list item(ViewPager) should have a list of images fetched from the Internet.

Comment: Any problems in doing so?

Comment: yes, the first list item only shows the images and if I scroll it that item also get invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a horizontal touch gesture inside a vertical touch gesture view, the user experience would be poor if you just put the `ViewPager` inside a `ListView`. I found this somewhere and I use it, it works very well. If you put your `ViewPager`s inside this, the user experience is good.

```
public class ViewPagerCompatibleListView extends ListView {
    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

    public ViewPagerCompatibleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
             lastX = ev.getX();
             lastY = ev.getY();
             break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             final float curX = ev.getX();
             final float curY = ev.getY();
             xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
             yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
             lastX = curX;
             lastY = curY;
             if (xDistance > yDistance)
                 return false;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```